# Better way to iteratively extend a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to collapse `multiple_get` into as few lines as possible?

```
def single_get(target):
    return [some list of objects] # might be an empty list 

def multiple_get(targets):
    result = []
    for target in targets:
        result.extend(single_get(target))
    return result
```

Comment: This code looks a bit sketchy. Please fill it in with real code so that we can advise you properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) library in general, for list-and-sequence-manipulating commands. You're looking for a way to "flatten" a list of lists; `itertools` calls this [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
def multiple_get(targets):
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(single_get(target) for target in targets))
```

However, Python can do it natively as a nested list comprehension:

```
def multiple_get(targets):
    return [r for target in targets for r in single_get(target)]
```

Comment: If you prefer functional programming style to list comprehensions, you could also use `itertools.chain(map(single_get, target))`.